# Selectively prevent rotate transform on child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following dom structure, in which I don't want transform to apply on some child divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z29Ez/

I tried using

```
transform:none
```

but it doesn't work.

I tried reversing the transform on the child element but it changes the position of the child element. Just un-comment the two Rotate functions in the fiddle and see the position of green div. I want it to retain its original position after the transform.

In IE11 the transform doesn't apply on the div's i don't want perhaps because the green div has `position:fixed;`. I want the same behavior on chrome and firefox.

Comment: You should set the transform origin property. If you manage to have the same origin for both rotations, the "counter rotation" will work.

Comment: @web-tiki Didn't work, can you show it by modifying the fiddle.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Here is an updated fiddle with all of the inline styles removed - http://jsfiddle.net/Z29Ez/2/. I see a function call, based on a specific rectangle class, to each of the rectangles. If you don't want a rectangle to transform, then don't call it in a function, right? When I transform each div, the other doesn't move.

Comment: @TimSPQR Just un-comment the first rotate function, that is what i want to do, but it transforms the child divs with position:fixed too, to revert the transform uncomment the second rotate function, but the position of green div is not restored to 20px, 30px

Comment: Here's my updated fiddle - I removed the second copy of the green div - http://jsfiddle.net/Z29Ez/4/. I see a green rectangle in the upper left and a white rectangle in the center. If I uncomment the upper function call, the large white rectangle rotates, the green rectangle does nothing. I reset the fiddle, and uncomment the second line function call. The green rectangle rotates and the white rectangle does nothing.

Comment: @TimSPQR That only occurs in IE and not in firefox 29 and chrome34, which browser are you using. The first function rotates both the rectangles in firefox and chrome

Comment: Ok, I check in Chrome and it rotates both. Let me play around a bit and see what I can do. Why do you have to rotate the whole parent and not just the individual children?

Comment: Very interesting - I made a test fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5BGGW/ - and then played with it on the three browsers. If you position: fixed the first inside div, it will NOT rotate in IE, but does rotate in Chrome and FF. You may have to go to just rotating individual elements within the holder div.